# Css flex overflow issue

Tags: css, flexbox

I have:

```
.container {
    display:flex;
    align-items:center
}
.content {
    flex-grow:1
}
```

in order to align the `.content` div vertically with css only. The content changes dynamically and that's why I can't use `position:absolute; margin-top:50%...` styling. Because I never know the exact height of `div` on each content update.

But in a scenario where `.container` width changes but height remains, `.content` overflows `.container` top because it wraps the text within.

What I'm trying to do is never let `.content` exceed the top position less than 0. Even the most ideal situation will be preserving the `padding-top` value of `.container` and `margin-top` value of `.content`. Overflowing bottom will be OK, in fact it'll be my preference.

Any workarounds?

Comment: Can you post the html?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make `.container` `height` flexible: use `min-height` instead of `height`.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  min-height: 75px;
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
.content {
  height: 150px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 3px solid red;
  resize: vertical;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Another possibility is using `overflow: auto`. However, instead of centering using `align-items:center`, use `margin: auto 0`.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 75px;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  overflow: auto;
  resize: vertical;
}
.content {
  height: 150px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: auto 0;
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```